# Is there any option to post to a user's friends' walls without using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook

Facebook has removed the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API.
Is there any other option to post to a user's friends' walls, when the friend is offline? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Well - they removed that feature... so no. You won't be able to post to a users wall *via the API*.  It makes no difference however, if the friend is online or offline.

What you will be able to do ([as the roadmap states](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)) is simply display a [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to your users - they can always be able to post on peoples wall in this way.

There is also some social plugins that allow users to post links to other users. Which plugin you use depends on what exactly you want to allow your users to do.

Quoting from the [send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) documentation :

> While the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) allows users to share content with all of their
>   friends, the Send Button allows them to send a private message to just
>   a few friends.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have gone through the code of Feed Dialog and Send Button.

The way our application work was, it stores facebook friend id and authetication token using publish stream, and later another windows service was posting one image and URL to freinds wall using this authetication token and facebook graph API.

Since facebook has removed the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph API, windows service is failing to post.
Error is:

Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application", OAuthException","code":200. 

Any other way for this?

Comment: If there was any other way, they would have disabled it as well. If you are looking for a way to completely bypass this and hack your way around this limitation then I'm afraid it is not in the scope of this post and I would highly discourage you from trying as your application could be blocked completely...